# .NET how to fudge the HttpContext object

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

for a unit test I am trying to add a value to the HttpApplicationState object, which is the Application property of the HttpContext.Current class. I try with the following code

```
        TextWriter tw = new StringWriter();
        HttpWorkerRequest wr = new SimpleWorkerRequest("/webapp", @"path...", "logon.asp", "", tw);

        HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(wr);

        //I try the following 2 lines
        HttpContext.Current.Application["KeyValue"] = "myValue";
        HttpContext.Current.Application.Add("KeyValue", "myValue");

        var count = HttpContext.Current.Application.Count;
        var get1 = HttpContext.Current.Application["KeyValue"];
        var get2 = HttpContext.Current.Application.Get("KeyValue");
```

But HttpContext.Current.Application.Count is always zero. The values do not get

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of .NET you're targeting you might want to look into [HttpContextBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.aspx) and [HttpContextWrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextwrapper.aspx). HttpContextBase is abstract so mocking frameworks like moq will allow you to assign its properties anyway you choose.

Comment: using .NET framework 3.5 actually. Those classes are for .NET 4

Comment: ah you're correcct. Still having problems getting it working though. HttpContext doesn't inherit from HttpContextBase so i can't create my own class and use that instead or am I missing somehthing?

Comment: in your app you have to wrap the usage of HttpContext with HttpContextWraper(HttpContext.Current). The wrapper returns HttpContextBase

Comment: Yes it returns HttpContextBase which is not the same as type HttpContext as HttpContext does not inherit it. So i cannot use HttpContextWraper as a substitute for HttpContext i.e. i cannot do HttpContext.Current = HttpContextWraper which is what i want to do as the method i am testing, that cannot be refactored, uses HttpContext.Current.Application

Comment: ok, then you'd have to look into something like this http://haacked.com/archive/2007/06/19/unit-tests-web-code-without-a-web-server-using-httpsimulator.aspx...