# .NET: how can I unit test this method?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

(Similar to [.NET how to fudge the HttpContext object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214812)!)

I have a method that I want to test:

```
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Application["myValue"] != null)
            Console.WriteLine("Boo!");
    }
```

How can I write a test WITHOUT refactoring the method so that the `Console.WriteLine` is hit?

I tried with:

```
        TextWriter tw = new StringWriter();
        HttpWorkerRequest wr = new SimpleWorkerRequest("/webapp", @"path...", "logon.asp", "", tw);
        HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(wr);
        HttpContext.Current.Application.Add("KeyValue", "myValue");
        MyMethod();
```

but HttpContext.Current.Application.count is always zero, I cannot add values to it!

Comment: Mocking the HttpContext is very hard. If you can't refactor or redesign this, try a mocking framework.

Comment: Hi Steven. Try a mocking framework? If you think i can do this without refactoring the method then please write an asnwer and explane. I don't think it's possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `HttpSimulator` class from [www.koders.com - Subtext.TestLibrary](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid2274359C5AC2884D2CE293A23E33516EAFF211D4.aspx?s=system#L1)

Just invoking

```
new Subtext.TestLibrary.HttpSimulator().SimulateRequest();
```

sets your `HttpContext` properly, so you can also add values to `Application` dictionary.

As Jeff said, it sets `HttpApplicationFactory._theApplicationFactory._state` using Reflection as below, but you don't have to bother about it, actually.

```
Type appFactoryType = Type.GetType("System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a");
object appFactory = ReflectionHelper.GetStaticFieldValue<object>("_theApplicationFactory", appFactoryType);
ReflectionHelper.SetPrivateInstanceFieldValue("_state", appFactory, HttpContext.Current.Application);
```

Answer (score 4):

The thing is you *should* refactor this method so that it's easier to test! To properly test this you want to mock `HttpContext` (here's one example as to how: [How to use Rhino Mocks to Mock an HttpContext.Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705833/how-to-use-rhino-mocks-to-mock-an-httpcontext-application)).

Comment: +1 - or better yet, pass the value contained in `HttpContext.Current.Application["myValue"]`.

Comment: If I refactor the method then i've no problem testing it. There are always reasons why you may not be able to refactor a method e.g. seniour managment say NO. So is the answer to my question no, it cannot be done?

Answer (score 3):

If you're specifically prohibited from refactoring the method and are also required to test it, you can use a detouring system, such as [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) or [TypeMock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/typemock-isolator-product3), to completely detour the static and HttpContext calls.  This can get a bit ugly, however and it's much preferable to perform refactoring on the original code.

---

Sequence of detoured mocks would be:

1. Detour HttpContext.Current to return a HttpContext detour stub (your own implementation that complies with the HttpContext class interface, but looks exactly like HttpContext to the tested code.)
2. In your HttpContext detour stub, mock Application["myValue"] to return your desired value (either null or non-null in this case.)  This will probably require creating a detour class for the return value of Application.
3. Now you can configure the detours and run your method.  The calls to HttpContext.Current and the HttpContext methods will be rerouted through the Profiling API to your detour stubs.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpContext.Application` is supplied by a private singleton that you can't access normally.

You *may* be able to set this via reflection, but I personally wouldn't even bother.

Instead you should isolate your testable code from global state like `HttpContext.Current`: just pass the value you're looking for into the method you want to test.

You can see the problem clearly looking at the code in [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) (or in the .NET source if you've downloaded that): the `HttpContext.Application` get accessor returns a new `HttpApplicationState` instance *every time you call it* unless something (like the ASP.NET framework) sets `HttpApplicationFactory._theApplicationFactory._state`.